# OpenLayers : Map not loading

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

If I use a single WMS layer as map base layer it loads the map, but adding different layers like (Google, Yahoo) to map it won't work. Can anyone tell me how to overcome this...
please check this:

```
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3.3" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://api.maps.yahoo.com/ajaxymap?v=3.0&appid=abcdefg1234" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;  
        function init() {
           map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
           var googleLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google", { 'sphericalMercator': true,
           'maxExtent': new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34, -20037508.34, 20037508.34, 20037508.34)});
           var wmsLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("OpenLayers WMS",                             "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0", { layers: 'basic' });
           var yahooLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Yahoo("Yahoo");
           map.addLayers([googleLayer, wmsLayer, yahooLayer]);
           map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(75.5, 8.5), 5);
           map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
           map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: can you clarify "doesn't work"?

Comment: it doesn't load the map. I've fiddle the code please check : http://jsfiddle.net/4psyk/

Comment: I've found that it is because of the yahoo layer, and i removed it. But there is other problems. first one: map center in google and wms layers are different. second: longitude and latitude values of google layer is higher. how to solve this please help me to learn. I've fiddle my code here please check : http://jsfiddle.net/8bMHS/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is the problem of projection or resolution.

try to use OSM instead of "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0".

```
map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: in fact that server does handle 900913 so it should work - http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?service=wms&request=getcapabilities

Comment: try to use [this](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/google-v3.html) example codes instead of yours.

Comment: That example is only for google layer, but i'm trying to combine two or more different layers

Comment: @bios add this line `map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());` to google map example which i have given above. i have tested, it was working...

Comment: @Aragon :can you please update that fiddle with that code, and please post that link

Comment: Are you still insist on using vmap0.tiles? or can OSM() work for you?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4433/discussion-between-bios-and-aragon)